# deploy key is note showing in open shift on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: openshift-client-tools

root@ubuntu:~# rhc setup
OpenShift Client Tools (RHC) Setup Wizard

This wizard will help you upload your SSH keys, set your application namespace,
and check that other programs like Git are properly installed.

If you have your own OpenShift server, you can specify it now. Just hit enter to
use the server for OpenShift Online: openshift.redhat.com.
Enter the server hostname: |openshift.redhat.com| sajeer850@gmail.com

You can add more servers later using 'rhc server'.

The OpenShift server is not responding correctly.  Check that
'https://sajeer850@gmail.com/broker/rest/api' is the correct URL for your
server. The server may be offline or misconfigured.

root@ubuntu:~# 'https://sajeer850@gmail.com/broker/rest/api'

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error . When prompted to Enter the server hostname: |openshift.redhat.com| press "Enter key" , and then you will be prompted to enter username and password.